# Just installed Yubico Yubikey for multifactor autentication and my MS Hotmail account in Evolution is suddenly failing authentication

Tags: gnome, email, authentication, evolution, yubikey

I have just installed Yubikey and the authentication works for everything except now I have an authentication issue with my MS Hotmail account in Gnome evolution.  I have uninstalled and re-added the account as a Gnome online account so it will be picked up in Evolution but it continues to fail authentication on Evolution startup and any refresh.  Just want to confirm whether the Yubikey addition and this new error are related and if anyone else has experienced this error?

Comment: What exactly did you install/activate? There are various ways to use a Yubikey on Linux. From your description alone it is not clear what you have done.

Comment: I configured the key for login and TTY as per the guide here https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649099-Ubuntu-Linux-Login-Guide-U2F

Comment: Hm, looks unlikely to me that the Yubikey should be the issue here, but I have never used it that way. You could confirm by simply removing the lines you added to the pam config and see if it works again then...

Comment: Somehow, mysteriously, access has returned although I made no changes.  Thank you for your help anyway, @Sebastian